# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split') when using import { cloudinary } from "cloudinary"

Tags: javascript, meteor, cloudinary

I've never encountered this before.

Im using Meteor.js

step 1. meteor npm install cloudinary
step 2. in a client side file I import the package import { Cloudinary } from "cloudinary";

when I run meteor locally I get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post a [mre]. We can't guess what you're doing wroing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what have mentioned by Kelly in his response, you are importing a backend package for your front-end application.

Cloudinary doesn't have an SDK built for Meteor, but you can still use the Javascript SDK.

Here's the documentation for Cloudinary's Javascript SDK: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/javascript_integration

Answer (score 2):

What is very likely happening here is that you are importing a package meant to only run on the server into a client environment and something that is expected to be available within the server environment is not available on the client.

If you want to work with cloudinary on the client side you'll need to use one of their client libraries, either their legacy `cloudinary-core` or their new sdk `@cloudinary/url-gen`. You will of course still need to use the `cloudinary` package on the server to create methods and such for signing your uploads or proxying the uploads through your server to cloudinary.

If you want to bypass some of this work you could use the `socialize:cloudinary` package which does quite a bit of the setup for you.

https://packosphere.com/socialize/cloudinary